# In Tcl, is there a performance problem to store dictionaries inside a list (to return it from a procedure with other values)?

Tags: tcl, procedure

I need to have a procedure that return a dictionary and a status value (ok/fail). currently the procedure return only the status and I use a global dictionary to be able to read/write inside it.

I wonder if I can return the dictionary in the procedure by using a list that will store the status value + the dictionary. I tried and it is working. a list can store a dictionary. it seems the dictionary is transformed as a list a values like this :

```
key1 value1 key2 value2, etc.
```

Then I can store the list of the dictionary inside a new dictionary and read it as a dictionary.

It is working but is it correct in term of performance ? for instance my dictionary will store more than 10 000 values. will it be awful to store it inside a list and then move it in a new dictionary to read it as a dictionary ?

Answer (score 2):

There's basically no performance penalty for storing a dictionary in a list; everything internally is handled by reference so it's all trivially easy that way.

The only exception to that is when you want to update a dictionary inside a list. This is because the operations to perform updates expect either to take a dictionary value or to be given the name of a variable containing a dictionary; the case where there's a list of dictionaries was not catered to (because it's relatively rare). You can, of course, use `lindex` to get the dictionary out of the list, but then you end up with (at least) two references to the dictionary at the point when you perform the update, forcing data to be copied (which is usually costly). You avoid that by removing the dictionary from the list, performing the update, and then putting it back.

It's a bit clearer to package that up as a procedure:

```
proc lindexDictSet {listVarName index key value} {
    upvar 1 $listVarName lst

    # Take dict and replace with empty string to remove unwanted reference
    set dct [lindex $lst $index]
    lset lst $index "";  # Constants are virtually free

    # Update the dictionary
    dict set dct $key $value

    # Put back
    lset lst $index $dct
}
```

Handling errors sensibly (such as the value at the index not being a dictionary) is left as an exercise.

Example use of the above:

```
% set x {{a 123 b 234} {c 345 d 456}}
{a 123 b 234} {c 345 d 456}
% lindexDictSet x 0 a 321
{a 321 b 234} {c 345 d 456}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested lists and dictionaries are valid and performant (for the reasons Donal gave), but I find the syntax for working with values in this way cumbersome, so it's one of the situations where I reach for [rl_json](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json) (full disclosure: I'm the author of rl_json so of course I'm hopelessly biased) even though nothing will be consuming the data in JSON format:

```
package require rl_json
namespace import ::rl_json::json

proc do_thing task {
    if {$task in {first third}} {
        set upper [string toupper $task]
        json template {
            {"status": "ok", "upper": "~S:upper"}
        }
    } else {
        json template {
            {"status": "failed", "errmsg": "example failure"}
        }
    }
}

set results {[]}

foreach task {first second third} {
    # set end+1 - like lappend - adds a new element to the end of the array
    # Can also set -1 to prepend the new element, which is less easy for lists
    json set results end+1 [do_thing $task]
    if {[json get $results end status] eq "ok"} {
        json set results end qc_checked true
    } else {
        puts "task failed: [json get $results end errmsg]"
    }
}

puts "Report: [json pretty $results]"
```

prints:

```
task failed: example failure
Report: [
    {
        "status":     "ok",
        "upper":      "FIRST",
        "qc_checked": true
    },
    {
        "status": "failed",
        "errmsg": "example failure"
    },
    {
        "status":     "ok",
        "upper":      "THIRD",
        "qc_checked": true
    }
]
```

It's not a failing of the `dict` (or `lindex` / `lset` / etc.) commands that make this case difficult to model with nested lists and dictionaries, but a subtle consequence of the way types work in Tcl: values only properly have a type in the moment you look at them - so the command doing the "looking" determines what type of thing the value is for the duration of that operation.  The next command could treat it as a different thing, and provided that the string permits that interpretation, everything is good (EIAS - Everything Is A String, really: All Values Are Strings).

The list and dictionary "types", which are by far the most commonly used schemes for working with compound values in Tcl, have mutually ambiguous string representations: a dictionary is a string with the same representation as a list with an even number of elements, with each pair of elements defining a key and value in the dictionary.  This is actually great, and enables a lot of cool things, but it fundamentally prevents a command operating on that compound value from knowing whether a nesting level in the compound structure is a dictionary or a list, which is context it would need to have to interpret an index into the structure.  Since every member of the set of values that can form a link in the index chain is a valid value for a key in a dictionary, there is nowhere in the index itself to resolve this question, so the context must come from the referenced level in the compound structure.  But that is ambiguous too for nested lists and dicts, so it's just not possible, without baking knowledge about the structure into the command, as Donal's example does.

Using JSON as the container for the compound value structure resolves this because the string representation of JSON unambiguously identifies the type of container at a given depth of nesting, providing the context necessary to interpret, say, `end+1` in the example as "one beyond the last element in the array", rather than the literal string key "end+1" in a JSON object (or Tcl dict).  It's also this property that permits pretty printing the compound structure, since the structural interpretation of each nested level is a property of the value, rather than the command accessing it as in the list/dict case.

Behind the scenes the values you store in the JSON are in reality stored in Tcl list and dictionary objects, so the same performance considerations and advantages apply as do in the native dicts / lists case, except that the `dict` command is in the core and byte-code compiled which avoids some overhead so it can be slightly faster for simple cases (and also because Donal is just a better programmer than I am...).  But I have found that when you add in the additional work to dance around nested structures of lists and dicts then the same thing using rl_json is faster overall, particularly when your code is running in a container, which incurs a heavy cost for Tcl (and almost all interpreted scripting languages) because the speculative decoding / execution vulerability mitigations that are turned on by default for containers which hit the bytecode dispatch engines of Tcl and python particularly hard, so fewer (Tcl) command executions start to matter.

Comment: Nice! I've been looking for a simple solution for handling JSON in tcl to communicate with LSP. I'll definitely take a look

Comment: Do you mind if I include it in my editor (https://github.com/slebetman/tcled)?

Comment: You're most welcome to use it anywhere.  It's BSD licensed like the Tcl core, but philosophically I think of the stuff I release as public domain (and usually make that explicit in recent projects).  Copyright for rl_json is owned by my employer (Ruby Lane) and my agreement with them is to release it as open source under the BSD license, so those are the terms that apply.  But there shouldn't be any reasonable use that precludes.